# Можно ли по словарю инициализоровать переменные класса. Python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, словари, инициализация

Можно ли каким-то образом присвоить каждой переменной класса значения переданные в словаре. К примеру, у класса есть переменные: A, B, C, D -, и я передаю конструктору класса словарь:

```
dictionary = {'B': 5, 'A': 2, 'C': 45}
```

Конструктор должен обратиться к переменным класса по именам ключей из словаря и задать им эти значение, при этом ключи могут находиться в произвольном порядке.

Пример класса:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, d: dict):
        self.A, self.B, self.C = int
        # тут должен быть код для инициализации переменных переданных в словаре

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       dictionary = {'B': 5, 'A': 2, 'C': 45}
       ex = Example(dictionary)
       print(ex.B)  # Должно вывести: "5".
```

Comment: Приведите пример вашего класса.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно через оператор `**` разложить значения словарей в аргументы конструктора:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, A, B, C):
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C

dictionary = {'B': 5, 'A': 2, 'C': 45}
foo = Foo(**dictionary)
print(foo.A, foo.B, foo.C)
# 2 5 45
```

Comment: А у вас ответ покруче будет) Спасибо, полезно

Comment: @SmellyNS, пожалуйста, у меня еще есть совет для вашего ответа :) Используйте `get` вместо `[]`, тогда вернется `None` если ключа нет: `self.A = dictionary.get('A')`. И вы зря удалили, ваш ответ имеет право, т.к. вариант с `**` имеет ограничения например лишние ключи в словаре вызовут ошибку

Comment: Как много нового я узнаю сегодня) Благодарю вдвойне. PS сначала подумал, что совет - это намёк на удаление ))

Comment: У меня два вопроса: где можно подробнее почитать про про две звёздочки и, второе, можно ли сделать так, чтобы пользователь передавал просто словарь без двух звёздочек?

Comment: @SmellyNS, когда оформляете ответ, я думаю, лучше его делать самодостаточным :)

Comment: @llollcat, насчет первого, погуглите `python dict unpack`, а насчет второго, вам поможет другой ответ

Comment: @gil9red Согласен, но иногда одновременно помочь хочется и полениться тоже :)

Comment: @llollcat, лучше примите другой ответ, он больше подходит под ваш вопрос :)

Answer (score 2):

В конструкторе класса для каждого элемента.

```
self.A = dictionary.get('A')
```

Пример:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, dictionary: dict):
        self.A = dictionary.get('A')
        self.B = dictionary.get('B')
        self.C = dictionary.get('C')

dictionary = {'B': 5, 'A': 2, 'C': 45, 'D': 111}
foo = Foo(dictionary)
print(foo.A, foo.B, foo.C)
# 2 5 45
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, dictionary: dict):
        for attr in dictionary:
            setattr(self, attr, dictionary[attr])

    # def __init__(self, dictionary: dict):
    #     self.__dict__.update(dictionary)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dictionary = {'B': 5, 'A': 2, 'C': 45}
    foo = Foo(dictionary)
    print(foo.A, foo.B, foo.C)  # 2 5 45
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for i in range(2,12):
    if i != 11:
      Name=tabel.find_element(By.XPATH,f"/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[1]").text
      Value=tabel.find_element(By.XPATH,f"/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[2]").text
      charateridic[f"{Name}"] = Value
      continue
```

У меня сработало так, надеюсь помог

Comment: Зря надеетесь, что помогли автору. Вопросу 2 года с лишним...

Comment: Ну другие люди будут искать, и могут наткнутся

Comment: ответить-то можно, это нормально, "надеюсь помог" заставило подумать, что вы дату вопроса не заметили. комментарий был в рамках стандартной проверки "первых сообщений" просто обратить внимание